# How to check if the application is foreground or background now?

Tags: javascript, capacitor

Capacitor provides an [App](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/app) plugin that allows to [get a call back](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/app#method-addListener-0) when the application goes background or foreground. But how to get the application `isActive` value (a.k.a. foreground/background state) at any moment? The problem is that I don't know the application state until I subscribe to the `appStateChange` event AND the app goes background or foreground.

Comment: I've reported a feature request to Capacitor developers: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2500

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A method to get the current state was [added](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/2611) recently:

```
import {Plugins} from '@capacitor/core';

const {App} = Plugins;

let {isActive} = await App.getState();
```

Comment: This is not true for Android. If you have a plugin, which starts a new Activity, the State will be inActive and the 'appStateChange' event will be fired.

Comment: Just found out that getState() returns a promise so you will need something like `const { isActive } = await App.getState()` in an async function or `App.getState().then(({ isActive }) => {// do your stuff})` (using  "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.7")

Answer (score 1):

`document.hasFocus()`

This will return a boolean. If the tab the web-app is in has the focus then it will return `true` else it will return `false`

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately `document.hasFocus()` doesn't always match the app state. Examples: 1) when I open recent apps list on iOS, `appStateChange` is fired with `isActive === false` but `document.hasFocus()` returns `true`; 2) when I focus on the console in a browser, `appStateChange` isn't fired but `document.hasFocus()` returns `false`.